# How to extract mail subject from subfolder of outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook

I am able to extract mail's subject from my outlook root folder.

```
Outlook.Application test_app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace test_space = test_app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.MAPIFolder test_folder = test_space.Folders["TanRong.Loo@infineon.com"].Folders["Test"];
foreach (Outlook.MailItem items in test_folder.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(items.Subject);
}
```

However, when I try to access the subfolder of my root "Test" folder, it gives me an error message.

```
Outlook.Application test_app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace test_space = test_app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.MAPIFolder test_folder = test_space.Folders["TanRong.Loo@infineon.com"].Folders["Test"].Folders["Test1"];
foreach (Outlook.MailItem items in test_folder.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(items.Subject);
}
```

The error message is:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem'. 
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00063034-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
at outlook_to_excel.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\LooTanRo\Desktop\Outlook Export\CS\outlook_to_excel\outlook_to_excel\Program.cs:line 51
```

What did i do wrong? Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of the objects in test_folder.Items?

Comment: Mailitems only. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming you only have `MailItem` objects in the folder. You can also have `ReportItem` or `MeetingItem` objects.
Change the loop to

```
foreach (object item in test_folder.Items)
{
  Outlook.MailItem mItem = item as Outlook.MailItem;
  if (mItem != null) 
  {
     ...
```

Comment: i'm not sure, but can he use this: `foreach (var item in test_folder.Items.OfType<Outlook.MailItem>()) { ... }`?